# Passing an identifier to a module in React

Tags: reactjs

Apologies, I probably have all of my terminology wrong here, but I am chunking up a React app into modules and am trying to combine two modules which do the same thing and come into an issue.

Specifically, I am trying to sum up totals of both income and expenditure, and have been calling two different react classes via:

`<ExpenditureTotal type={this.state.cashbook.expenditure} addTotal={this.addTotal} />` and another `<IncomeTotal...` which does the same).

The Class is as follows (expenditure shown, but income is the same:

```
/* Expenditure Running Total */
var ExpenditureTotal = React.createClass({
  render: function() {

    var expIds = Object.keys(this.props.expenditure);
    var total = expIds.reduce((prevTotal, key) => {
      var expenditure = this.props.expenditure[key];
      return prevTotal + (parseFloat(expenditure.amount));
    }, 0);

    this.props.addTotal('expenditure', total);

    return(
      <h2 className="total">Total: {h.formatPrice(total)}</h2>
    );
  }
});
```

I wanted to combine the two by making it more generic, so I made the following:

```
/* Cashflow Running Total */
var TotalCashflow = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var expIds = Object.keys(this.props.type);
    var total = expIds.reduce((prevTotal, key) => {
      var type = this.props.type[key];
      return prevTotal + (parseFloat(type.amount));
    }, 0);

    this.props.addTotal('type', total);

    return(
      <h2 className="total">Total: {h.formatPrice(total)}</h2>
    );
  }
});
```

The only reason it doesn't work properly is when I add the summed total to the relevant state object which for this is income or expenditure in totals: `(totals: { income: val, expenditure: val})`.
Where I was previously explicitly specifying 'expenditure' or 'income' in the module, (seen above in ExpenditureTotal as `this.props.addTotal('expenditure', total);`, I am not sure in React how to pass the total value to the relevant place - it needs to read either 'expenditure' or 'income' to populate the correct state totals key.

Apologies if this is a bit garbled, struggling to explain it clearly.

Thank you :)

**Update: App component in full:**

```
import React from 'react';

// Firebase
import Rebase from 're-base';
var base = Rebase.createClass("FBURL")

import h from '../helpers';

import Expenditure from './Expenditure';
import Income from './Income';
import TotalCashflow from './TotalCashflow';
import AddForm from './AddForm';
import Available from './Available';

var App = React.createClass({

  // Part of React lifecycle
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      cashbook: {
        expenditure: {},
        income: {}
      },
      totals: {},
      available: {}
    }
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    // Two way data binding
    base.syncState('cashbook', {
      context: this,
      state: 'cashbook'
    });
  },

  addExpenditure: function(expenditure) {
    var timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();
    // update state object
    this.state.cashbook.expenditure['expenditure-' + timestamp] = expenditure;
    // set state
    this.setState({
      cashbook: { expenditure: this.state.cashbook.expenditure }
    });
  },
  addIncome: function(income) {
    var timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();
    // update state object
    this.state.cashbook.income['income-' + timestamp] = income;
    // set state
    this.setState({
      cashbook: { income: this.state.cashbook.income }
    });
  },
  removeExpenditure: function(key) {
    this.state.cashbook.expenditure[key] = null;
    this.setState({
      cashbook: { expenditure: this.state.cashbook.expenditure }
    });
  },
  renderExpenditure: function(key) {
    var details = this.state.cashbook.expenditure[key];
    return(
      <tr className="item" key={key}>
        <td><strong>{details.name}</strong></td>
        <td><strong>{h.formatPrice(details.amount)}</strong></td>
        <td>{details.category}</td>
        <td>{details.type}</td>
        <td>{details.date}</td>
        <td><button className="remove-item" onClick={this.removeExpenditure.bind(null, key)}>Remove</button></td>
      </tr>
    );
  },
  removeIncome: function(key) {
    this.state.cashbook.income[key] = null;
    this.setState({
      cashbook: { income: this.state.cashbook.income }
    });
  },
  renderIncome: function(key) {
    var details = this.state.cashbook.income[key];
    return(
      <tr className="item" key={key}>
        <td><strong>{details.name}</strong></td>
        <td><strong>{h.formatPrice(details.amount)}</strong></td>
        <td>{details.category}</td>
        <td>{details.type}</td>
        <td>{details.date}</td>
        <td><button className="remove-item" onClick={this.removeIncome.bind(null, key)}>Remove</button></td>
      </tr>
    );
  },
  listInventory: function() {
    return
  },
  addTotal: function(type, total) {
    this.state.totals[type] = total;
  },
  render: function() {

    return(
      <div className="cashbook">

        <Expenditure
          cashbook={this.state.cashbook.expenditure}
          renderExpenditure={this.renderExpenditure} />

        <TotalCashflow
          type={this.state.cashbook.expenditure}
          addTotal={this.addTotal}
          identifier='expenditure'
          />

        <AddForm addCashflow={this.addExpenditure} />

        <Income
          cashbook={this.state.cashbook.income}
          renderIncome={this.renderIncome} />

        <TotalCashflow
          type={this.state.cashbook.income}
          addTotal={this.addTotal}
          identifier='income'
          />

        <AddForm addCashflow={this.addIncome} />

        <Available totals={this.state.totals} />

      </div>
    );
  }
});

export default App;
```

Comment: I believe what you call modules are components in React terminology. And `render` [should](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html) be pure: that is, it should not modify any state.

Comment: Instead of having `cashbook.expenditure`, have `cashbook.type = 'expenditure'` and for income as well.. then you can just access the type property to see which one you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you correctly, you want to have a component, that renders the totals of 'expenditure' and/or 'income'. Notice, you should not modify the state within the render function, as these will trigger over and over again, with each state change it is invoking itself.

Instead, try to compute the necessary data from within the parent components componentDidMount/componentDidUpdate, so that the TotalCashflow can be served the data, without it needing to do any more logic on it.

This might be the parent component:

```
/* Cashflow-Wrapper */
var TotalCashflowWrapper = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function(){
    this.setState({
        income: this.addTotal(/*x1*/)
        expenditure: this.addTotal(/*x1*/)
    });
    /*x1: hand over the relevant 'type' data that you use in the child components in your example*/
  }
  addTotal: function(type) {
    var expIds = Object.keys(type);
    return expIds.reduce((prevTotal, key) => {
       var x = type[key];
       return prevTotal + (parseFloat(x.amount));
    }, 0);
  }
  render: function() {
    return(
      <div>
         <TotalCashflow total={this.state.expenditure}/>
         <TotalCashflow total={this.state.income}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

This would be your total component:

```
   /* Cashflow Running Total */
    var TotalCashflow = React.createClass({
      render: function() {
        return(
          <h2 className="total">Total: {h.formatPrice(this.props.total)}</h2>
        );
      }
    });
```

### **Edit**

There are a few issues with your App component, but first of all, here is how you could redesign/simplify it. You should also move the markup from renderExpenditure and renderIncome to your Income/Expenditure components. I've been using ES6, as I've noticed you're already using arrow functions.

```
var App = React.createClass({
   getInitialState: function () {
      return {
         cashbook: {
            expenditure: {},
            income: {}
         },
         totals: {},
         available: {}
      }
   },

   componentDidMount: function () {
      // Two way data binding
      base.syncState('cashbook', {
         context: this,
         state: 'cashbook'
      }).then(()=> {
         // after syncing cashbook, calculate totals
         this.setState({
            totals: {
               income: this.getTotal(this.state.cashbook.income),
               expenditure: this.getTotal(this.state.cashbook.expenditure),
            }
         });
      });
   },

   // Get total of obj income/expenditure
   getTotal: function (obj) {
      var expIds = Object.keys(obj);
      return expIds.reduce((prevTotal, key) => {
         var type = obj[key];
         return prevTotal + (parseFloat(type.amount));
      }, 0);
   },

   addCashflow: function (identifier, amount) {
      var timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();
      // clone cashbook and clone cashbook[identifier] and set cashbook[identifier][identifier + '-' + timestamp] to amount
      var cashbook = {
         ...this.state.cashbook,
         [identifier]: {
            ...this.state.cashbook[identifier],
            [identifier + '-' + timestamp]: amount
         }
      };
      // set state
      this.setState({
         cashbook: cashbook,
         // Update totals
         totals: {
            ...this.state.totals,
            [identifier]: this.getTotal(cashbook[identifier])
         }
      });
   },

   removeCashflow: function (identifier, key) {
      // clone cashbook and clone cashbook[identifier]
      var cashbook = {...this.state.cashbook, [identifier]: {...this.state.cashbook[identifier]}};
      delete cashbook[identifier][key];
      this.setState({
         cashbook: cashbook,
         totals: {
            ...this.state.totals,
            // Update totals
            [identifier]: this.getTotal(cashbook[identifier])
         }
      });
   },

   render: function () {
      return (
         <div className="cashbook">
            <Expenditure cashbook={this.state.cashbook.expenditure} removeCashflow={(key)=>this.removeCashflow('expenditure', key)}/>
            <TotalCashflow total={this.state.cashbook.expenditure} identifier='expenditure'/>
            {/*or drop TotalCashflow and do <h2 className="total">Total: {h.formatPrice(this.state.totals.expandature)}</h2>*/}
            <AddForm addCashflow={(amount)=>this.addCashflow('expenditure', amount)}/>
            <Income cashbook={this.state.cashbook.income} removeCashflow={(key)=>this.removeCashflow('income', key)}/>
            <TotalCashflow type={this.state.cashbook.income} identifier='income' />
            <AddForm addCashflow={(amount)=>this.addCashflow('income', amount)}/>
            <Available totals={this.state.totals}/>
         </div>
      );
   }
});

export default App;
```

### Issues with your current App component

**Issue**: You are not removing the key, you're just setting it to null; this could lead to exceptions when iterating Object.keys() and you're expecting the values to be numbers, like when calculating the totals

```
removeIncome: function(key) {
      // this.state.cashbook.income[key] = null;
      delete this.state.cashbook.income[key]
      this.setState({
         cashbook: { income: this.state.cashbook.income }
      });
   },
```

**Bad design**: You're defining the markup of a child component within your parent component, although it seems unnecessary

```
renderExpenditure: function(key) {
    var details = this.state.cashbook.expenditure[key];
    return(
      <tr className="item" key={key}>
        <td><strong>{details.name}</strong></td>
        <td><strong>{h.formatPrice(details.amount)}</strong></td>
        <td>{details.category}</td>
        <td>{details.type}</td>
        <td>{details.date}</td>
        <td><button className="remove-item" onClick={this.removeExpenditure.bind(null, key)}>Remove</button></td>
      </tr>
    );
  },
```

This could easily be moved to your Expenditure/Income component.

**Issues**: Mutating state, Overwriting cashbook in state and loosing expenditure/income

```
addExpenditure: function(expenditure) {
      var timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();
      // You are mutating the state here, better clone the object and change the clone, then assign the cloned
      this.state.cashbook.expenditure['expenditure-' + timestamp] = expenditure;
      // You are overwriting cashbook with an object, that only contains expenditure, thus loosing other properties like income
      this.setState({
         cashbook: { expenditure: this.state.cashbook.expenditure }
      });
   }
```

// Fixed

```
addExpenditure: function(expenditure) {
      var timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();
      // clone object
      var cashbook = Object.assign({}, this.state.cashbook);
      cashbook.expenditure = Object.assign({}, cashbook.expenditure);
      // define latest expenditure
      cashbook.expenditure['expenditure-' + timestamp] = expenditure;
      // set state
      this.setState({
         cashbook: cashbook
      });
   }
```

// ES6

```
addExpenditure: function(expenditure) {
      var timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();
      this.setState({
         cashbook: {
          ...this.state.cashbook,
          expenditure: {
            ...this.state.cashbook.expenditure,
            ['expenditure-' + timestamp]: expenditure
          }
         }
      });
   }
```

You would be better off, if you'd flatten your state and cashbook object
so instead of

```
this.state = {
         cashbook: {
            expenditure: {},
            income: {}
         },
         totals: {},
         available: {}
      }
```

having

```
this.state = {
         expenditure: {},
         income: {}
         totals: {},
         available: {}
      }
```

so you could just

```
addExpenditure: function(expenditure) {
      var timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();
      var exp = Object.assign({}, this.state.cashbook.expenditure);
      exp['expenditure-' + timestamp] = expenditure;
      this.setState({
         expenditure: exp
      });
   }
```

or es6

```
addExpenditure: function(expenditure) {
      var timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();
      this.setState({
         expenditure: {
            ...this.state.cashbook.expenditure,
            ['expenditure-' + timestamp]: expenditure
         }
      });
   }
```

of course you'd need to update the rebase binding and your models, dunno if this is something you want

```
componentDidMount: function() {
      base.syncState('expenditure', {
         context: this,
         state: 'expenditure'
      });
      base.syncState('income', {
         context: this,
         state: 'income'
      });
   }
```

Comment: Thanks quambo. Struggling to implement this correctly at the moment, the states I need to update are in the App component, but in your example, you have set up completely new state objects?
Also, it is the App component that renders out the `<TotalCashflow type={this.state.cashbook.expenditure} addTotal={this.addTotal} />` but in yours it is rendered in a new component, so just unsure how to piece it all together.

Comment: This doesn't really matter, the Wrapper can easily be the App component. Just incorporate the features (componentDidMount, addTotal) into your App component, then you won't need the Wrapper and another state object. All that matters is, try to compute the data in the componentDidMount (not in the render function) in your parent component (App component), and serve the child data in the correct format, so it doesn't need to do any complex processing. If you want a better code example, you will need to provide more insight into your app component.

Comment: Thank you quambo. I will update my original post with the App component in full.

Comment: I've expanded my answer according to your App component.

Comment: Wow, that's fantastic. Thanks so much. Sorry I was out today, going to spend tomorrow morning going through it. You are very generous, thank you again :)

Comment: Hi quambo, been amending the app, and am now getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: base.syncState(...).then is not a function` from within componentDidMount in the App component. (Thanks for all your help on this).

Comment: Also, how would I re-work the remove button code now? Currently this is set as: `<button className="remove-item" onClick={this.removeExpenditure.bind(null, key)}>Remove</button>` but removeExpenditure no longer exists and is now `removeCashflow`.

Comment: hey zeKoko, I think we are starting to overexceeded the scope of this platform. Concerning the then try it like here, line 21: https://github.com/tylermcginnis/re-base/blob/896f252a27008f5aa42a39d278cdaff83453aaee/examples/todolist%20-%20syncState/app/App.js

Comment: and for the button, please take a look at the code I've written in the apps render function: removeCashflow={(key)=>this.removeCashflow('expenditure', key)}

Comment: Perfect! Except the remove. I used `onClick={this.props.removeCashflow('expenditure', key)}` and I get the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: identifier is not defined` from `App`: `......this.state, [identifier]: {...`. Going to mark this as resolved anyway as you have done loads on this already and it is a massive improvement. Thanks so much :)

Comment: Hey mate, make sure you use an inline function as in onClick={(key)=>this.props.removeCashflow('expenditure', key)}, not onClick={this.props.removeCashflow('expenditure', key)}!

Comment: Sorry quambo, last question, I promise. Using `<td><button className="remove-item" onClick={(key)=>this.props.removeCashflow('income', key)}>Remove</button></td>` for the remove button code in the Income component, but clicking remove does nothing, no console error either.
If I console.log `identifier` and `key` within the removeCashflow method, I get `income` and `income` for both, so it looks like the identifier is being passed as the key?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99725/discussion-between-quambo-and-zekoko).